# How to integrate MS Teams call recording in my web application?

Tags: angular, web-applications, microsoft-teams, call-recording, azure-communication-services

I am building an Angular-based web application. Using Azure Communication, I have achieved to integrate the video call functionality.

Now I am trying to integrate MS Teams call recording functionality. Kindly help with the reference link and solution.

Comment: Could you please provide more details?

Comment: There is no direct graph API to do this. You should give it a try what @rocky has suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to utilize the [Call Automation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/communication/callautomation/server-calls) in your app's backend. If your backend is running on .NET or Java, you can get up and running quickly by using the code from the quickstart apps:

- https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-dotnet-quickstarts/tree/main/ServerRecording
- https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-java-quickstarts/tree/main/ServerRecording

Those apps utilize the CallingServer SDKs which are available also only for .NET (on [NuGet](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/communication/Azure.Communication.CallingServer)) and Java (on [Maven](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/communication/azure-communication-callingserver)).

If your app is using a different stack on the backend (e.g. Node.js), you'll need to call the [Call Automation REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/communication/callautomation/server-calls) directly.
You can follow the [quickstart guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/call-recording-sample?pivots=programming-language-csharp) and replace the step `Start recording session using 'StartRecordingAsync' server API` with a [respective REST API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/communication/callautomation/server-calls/start-recording). Use the same approach, if you want to pause, resume, or stop the recording.

More resources:

- [Conceptual docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/voice-video-calling/call-recording)